# PHP. Запись в MySQL двух массивов

Tags: php, mysql

Жизнь злодейка заставила меня разбираться с MySQL
В общем, надо составить базу данных. В базе создается таблица с введённым из формы номером.

С этим я успешно покончил и даже полностью это осознал.
Теперь надо в форме ввести два соответствующих числа до 10 раз: 1)На какой номер указывает(от 1 до 699) 2)Расположение указателя (условная система координат из 1-2-...-9-a по X  и 1-2-...-6 по Y)
(указателей может быть несколько, не известно сколько)

Как записывать, разницы не имеет, главное, чтобы в базе данных хранился указатель и его расположение

Мне казалось, что было бы крайне легко использовать две формы и вводить с новой строки данные для каждого указателя. В одной форме - куда указывает, в другой - где находится. Ну и эти данные разбить на строки и в массив загнать

Система у меня работает так: сначала записывает несколько значений "куда" в один столбец, потом записывает "где находится" в другой, но не от начала, а начинает с того места, где закончилось "куда" (в принципе, я уже потом понял, что так и должно быть, но сначала не догадывался)

Пытался придумать, как значения "где находится" вставлять обновлением, но там совсем всё страшно и не получается таким же способом их вставлять(обновлять)
Код:

```
   <?php 
$Link = mysql_connect('localhost', '******', '****');

if(!$Link) echo "Не удалось подключится к серверу";
else
{
    mysql_select_db('*****');

    $LO = 'a'.$_POST['LO'];
    $nl_char="\n";
    $arr1=explode($nl_char,$_POST['to']);
    $arr2=explode($nl_char,$_POST['map']);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $LO (VedetK  VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, Location VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL)";
    if (mysql_query($sql))
        echo "Создание таблицы завершено \n";
    else
        echo "Таблицу создать не удалось  \n";

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO $LO (VedetK) VALUES (" . implode("), (", $arr1) . ")";


    if (mysql_query($query1))
        echo "всатвка удалась \n";
    else
        echo "не получилось вставить \n";
    $query2 = "UPDATE $LO (Location) VALUES (" . implode("), (", $arr2) . ")";


    if (mysql_query($query2))
        echo "всатвка 2 удалась \n";
    else
        echo "не получилось вставить 2 \n";
}
?>
```

Была идея объединить массивы с помощью array_combine, но дальнейшие действия у меня уже покрыты тайной, потому как не имею представления о вставке таких данных
В принципе, без разницы как записывать в формы ввода эти данные, можно хоть "куда","где", просто тут тоже не понимаю плана действий в дальнейшем

Поэтому прошу помощи с любым вариантом внесения сразу двух этих параметров в базу данных (либо сначала одного, а потом другого с первой строчки)
Альтернативный вариант: Как внести сразу два этих параметра (и как лучше настроить форму получения(в одной форме получать два параметра или в разных)), как внести сразу два параметра несколько раз?

*Гугление не сильно помогло* со всем этим
(Про безопасность и прочее лучше не упоминать, делается для личного и, в основном, разового использования)

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, суть вопроса.

Comment: А по какому условию вы обновляете запись? Не проще ли всё это записать одним запросом? Например из [этого](http://www.phplancer.ru/insert-update-mysql/) примера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так

```
<?php
$Link = mysql_connect('localhost', '******', '****');

function insert($insData)
{
    $columns = implode(", ", array_keys($insData));
    $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
    $values = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

    mysql_query($sql);
}

if(!$Link) echo "Не удалось подключится к серверу";
else
{
    mysql_select_db('*****');

    $LO = 'a'.$_POST['LO'];
    $nl_char="\n";
    $arr1=explode($nl_char,$_POST['to']);
    $arr2=explode($nl_char,$_POST['map']);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $LO (VedetK  VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, Location VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL)";
    if (mysql_query($sql))
        echo "Создание таблицы завершено \n";
    else
        echo "Таблицу создать не удалось  \n";

    if(count($arr1) != count($arr2)) {
        echo "массивы разного размера!";
        exit();
    }

    foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$value){
        $data = [
            'VedetK' => $arr1[$key],
            'Location' => $arr2[$key],
        ];

        insert($data);
    }


    if (mysql_query($query2))
        echo "всатвка 2 удалась \n";
    else
        echo "не получилось вставить 2 \n";


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример стандартного синтаксиса на вставку

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ....) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2..)
```

Обычно сначала мы подготавливаем массив вида

```
$insData = [
    'Location' => 'некое значение 1',
    'VedetK' => 'некое значение 2',
    ........
]
```

Где ключи массива - это имена полей в таблице, а его значения - те значения, которые мы хотим вставить в таблицу.

Затем мы производим вставку следующим образом

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

mysql_query($sql)
```

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том (да, я не очень хорошо могу объясняться), как подготовить этот самый массив этого вида, учитывая, что значений типа 1 и 2 может быть несколько (к примеру, пять разных пар)

Comment: просто добавляйте "пары" в массив $insData, в чем проблема?

Comment: С теми же ключами?

Comment: И, не подскажете, как из формы с сайта получить такой вид?